# getting value from firebase database by authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My android app has a string ,and i want to send it to the Firebase database for authentication.If that string matches "jhgkjgl",i want Firebase to send me the data ,otherwise not send anything.

What  do i have to write both in my java and firebase console?
What do i need to do?

rules:

```
{
"rules":{
".read":"auth.uid.matches(/jhgkjgl/)"
}
}
```

The data i want to get in my app :

```
q:"qqqweryty"
```

My path is:

```
https://fir-rial-8888.firebaseio.com/
```

I just want to use the string for authentication.If the string in my app matches that of server's ,i want to get the value of my key "q".

Comment: Make a chield to your firebase root dabase with a string (jhgkjgl) and retrive data from this path when this path equals to string then user can retrive the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you try something like ..

```
".read":"newData.val() == 'jhgkjgl'"
```