# Accessing data path in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

> Make a child to your firebase root database with a string (jhgkjgl) and
>   retrive data from this path when this path equals to string then user
>   can retrive the data

**Is it good way of restricting and authenticating access of data?**

As said by mr.narendra  in the comment in the below post:
[getting value from firebase database by authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39141727/6265154)

The post is as follows:

> My android app has a string ,and i want to send it to the Firebase
>   database for authentication.If that string matches "jhgkjgl",i want
>   Firebase to send me the data ,otherwise not send anything.
>
> What do i have to write both in my java and firebase console? What do
>   i need to do?
>
> rules:
>
> { "rules":{ ".read":"auth.uid.matches(/jhgkjgl/)" } } The data i want
>   to get in my app :
>
> q:"qqqweryty" My path is:
>
> https://fir-rial-8888.firebaseio.com/ I just want to use the string
>   for authentication.If the string in my app matches that of server's ,i
>   want to get the value of my key "q".

Comment: Why are you following up to a comment to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141727/getting-value-from-firebase-database-by-authentication) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing with a static value you can use a placeholder for that node.

Rules sample from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules).

If you do not want to authenticate users via authentication providers, you can use [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: will solution provided by Mr. narendra also work? He is saying that by making the string itself a path to my node ,so when path is valid ,i get the value,and when it isn't ,i don't.

Comment: my rules are gonna be "Rules":{"My string":{".read":true}}

Comment: data   is:  My string : "qqqweryty"

Comment: You could make your db access public, and then fetch data just by giving the node name. Or you may try defining a user from the console and authenticating with it in your application statically but this is in-secure.

Comment: So Mr. narendra 's solution is also safe..